# Ayuda con un JSP!

Tags: java, html, jsp

necesito mostrar un mensaje que tengo de un (try) en un jsp. Ya intenté con <%=NombreVariableDeMensaje%> pero no me funciona. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<%
int PUERTO = 4000;

try{

    System.out.println("Iniciando Servidor...");
    //Creamos un objeto de la clase ServerSockets para esperar conexiones por el puerto designado
    ServerSocket socket_servidor = new ServerSocket(PUERTO);
    //Imprimimos que estamos escuchando al puerto
    System.out.println("Escucho al puerto: " + PUERTO);
    System.out.println("Esperando conexiones de los clientes...");

    //Mediante un ciclo, restringimos la atención do sólo 3 clientes
    for(int numCliente = 0; numCliente < 200 ; numCliente++){

    double sl = 5.7;    
    double sw = 2.8;    
    double pl = 4.1;    
    double pw = 1.3;    


    String parametros = "{'sl':" + sl + ", 'sw':" + sw + ", 'pl':" + pl + ", 'pw':" + pw +"}" ; 

    //Creamos un objeto de la clase socket para gestionar las conexiones de cada cliente
    //El método .accept() crea un socket para atender a un cliente  que se ha conectado
    Socket socket_cliente = socket_servidor.accept();
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
    //Imprimimos en pantalla que estamos atendiendo al cliente #tal :v
    System.out.println("Sirvo al cliente : "+numCliente+", en el puerto de comunicación: " +  socket_cliente.getPort());
    //Creamos un stream de salida para enviar los mensajes a los clientes
    OutputStream mensajeParaCliente = socket_cliente.getOutputStream();
    //La clase DataOutStream es útil para escribir los datos de tipo primitivo de una forma portable
    DataOutputStream flujoSecuencial = new DataOutputStream(mensajeParaCliente);
    //Escribimos en el flujo secuencial del socket mediante el .writeUTF  y lo enviamos al cliente
    flujoSecuencial.writeUTF(parametros/*"Este es un mensaje enviado desde el servidor :v""Bienvenido cliente: " + numCliente + ".\n El puerto de eschucha es: " + socket_cliente.getLocalPort() + " y el puerto de comunicaciones bidereccional es: " + socket_cliente.getPort()*/ );
    //Creamos un stream de entrada para recibir todos los mensajes del cliente 
    InputStream is = socket_cliente.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader buf =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String mensaje = buf.readLine();
    System.out.println("El cliente " + numCliente + " Dice --> " + mensaje);

    socket_cliente.close(); 

    }


    System.out.println("Demasiados Clientes...");
    System.out.println("Solo puedo atender 3 clientes...");


    }catch(Exception e){

        System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 

    } 
%>
```

La variable que quiero mostrar es:

```
String mensaje = buf.readLine();
```

El código html es:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Calculadora Iris

### CALCULADORA IRIS

```
                        <form action="#" name="formulario">
                        <label> Sepal Length:
                                <input type="text" name="sl" size="3" maxlength="1"  readonly="readonly" value="<%=sl%>"/>
                            </label><br><br>

                            <label> Petal Length:
                                <input type="text" name="pl" size="3" maxlength="1" readonly="readonly" value="<%=pl%>"/>
                            </label><br><br>

                             <label> Sepal Width:
                                <input type="text" name="sw"  size="3" maxlength="1" readonly="readonly" value="<%=sw%>"/>
                            </label><br><br>


                            <label> Petal Width:
                                <input type="text" name="pw" size="3" maxlength="1"  readonly="readonly" value="<%=pw%>"/>
                            </label><br><br>

                        </form>
                </div>

            <form action="#" name="resultado">

                <div class="w3ls-bottom">
                    <strong>
                        <p>Esta especie es: <a id="especie"><%=clase%></a></p>
                    </strong>
                </div>
            </form>     
        </div>  
    </section>
</body>
```

Y quiero poner el mensaje en:

```
<p>Esta especie es: <a id="especie"><%=mensaje%></a></p>
```

Pero no lo toma...

De antemano, muchas gracias por leerme y ayudarme <3

Answer (score 0):

No puedes llamar la variable mensaje desde el JSP, tienes que enviarsela desde el controlador al JSP, existen varias formas pero una de ellas podría ser:

```
request.setAttribute("msj", mensaje);
```

donde "msj" es el nombre identificativo del atributo y mensaje el segundo parametro es la variable que vas a pasar.

luego desde el JSP en el HTML pones:

```
<p>Esta especie es: <a id="especie">${msj}</a></p>
```

Donde msj sería la variable que enviaste desde tu servlet.